# Properties of the optimal decomposition for the $K$-functional between $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sequences-and-series, interpolation-spaces

**Background:** For any fixed $t> 0$, the *$K$-functional* defines a norm on the space $\ell_1+\ell_2$:
$$
\lVert a\rVert_{K(t)} = \inf\{\lVert a'\rVert_1+ t\lVert a''\rVert_2 : a'\in\ell_1,\ a''\in\ell_2,\ a'+a''=a\}. \tag{1}
$$
For fixed $a$, the function $\kappa_a\colon t>0\mapsto \lVert a\rVert_{K(t)}$ is non-decreasing, concave, and continuous, and satisfies

- $\lim_{t\to 0^+} \kappa_a(t) = 0$
- $\frac{1}{4}\lVert a\rVert_1\leq \lim_{t\to \infty} \kappa_a(t) \leq \lVert a\rVert_1$

*(See e.g. [1].)* Moreover, if $a$ has finite support, then we get $\lim_{t\to \infty} \kappa_a(t) = \lVert a\rVert_1$ (actually, $\kappa_a(t)=\lVert a\rVert_1$ for any $t\geq \sqrt{\lvert \operatorname*{supp} a\rvert}$).

If $(a',a'')\in \ell_1\times\ell_2$ are such that $a=a'+a''$ and $\kappa_a(t) = \lVert a'\rVert_1+ t\lVert a''\rVert_2$, we say that $(a',a'')$ is an *optimal decomposition (of $a$) for $t$*.

In what follows, I focus on non-negative sequences, and even non-increasing non-negative sequences. *(Actually, I only need results for non-increasing non-negative sequences with finite support, if that makes a difference,)*

From what I could find and understand [2,3] (this is for functions in $L^1+L^2$, but seems to generalize to $\ell_1+\ell_2$), optimal decompositions are of the form:

$$a_k'' = \min(\lambda,a_k),\qquad a'_k = a_k - a_k'' \qquad k\in\mathbb{N}$$
for some $\lambda=\lambda(t) \geq 0$.

Seeing $(a',a'')$ (with some slight handwaving or technicalities in case of non-unicity) as functions of $t$ for $a$ fixed, this implies a specific case of a more general result [3], i.e. that 
$$
x\colon t\mapsto \lVert a'_t\rVert_1, \qquad y\colon t\mapsto \lVert a''_t\rVert_2
$$
are respectively non-decreasing and non-increasing.

> **Question:** Is there more we can say about the behavior of $x,y$? Specifically, I am interested in the regime of "large $t$", when $\kappa_a(t) = \lim_\infty\kappa_a -\eta$ for small $\eta$ (and the limit is finite, i.e. $a\in\ell_1$) but I'd be interested in any structural result on $x,y$. (Convexity, upper and lower bounds as a function of $\eta$, etc.)

If the question is too general, I can narrow it down as mentioned above by enforcing that $a$ be not only non-increasing and non-negative, but additionally with finite support.

---

[1] Astashkin, S.V. J. *Rademacher functions in symmetric spaces* Math Sci (2010) 169: 725. [doi:10.1007/s10958-010-0074-z](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10958-010-0074-z)

[2] Nilsson P., Peetre J., *On the $K$ functional between $L^1$ and $L^2$ and some other $K$-functionals*, Journal of Approximation Theory, Volume 48, Issue 3, 1986, Pages 322-327, ISSN 0021-9045, [doi:10.1016/0021-9045(86)90054-7](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904586900547)

[3] Optimal decompositions for the $K$-functional for a couple of Banach lattices. Cwikel, M. & Keich, U. Ark. Mat. (2001) 39: 27. [doi:10.1007/BF02388790](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02388790)

Comment: To be more specific: one thing that is rater immediate is that if for some $t>0$ we have an optimal decomposition $a',a''$, then $$\kappa_a(t) = \lVert a'\rVert_1+t\lVert a''\rVert_2= \lVert a-a''\rVert_1+t\lVert a''\rVert_2= \lVert a\rVert_1-\lVert a''\rVert_1+t\lVert a''\rVert_2$$ so that $$0\leq \lVert a''\rVert_2 =\frac{\lVert a''\rVert_1 - \lVert a\rVert_1 +\kappa_a(t) }{t}$$ and $$\lVert a''\rVert_1 \geq  \lVert a\rVert_1 -\kappa_a(t) $$
but that gives no non-trivial upper bound on $x(t)=\lVert a'\rVert_1$.